# Outputting a serialized object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

In Rails 2.3.6 I'm storing some serialized data in a database field.

My "feed_event.data" field in my database is stored as text and is (for example) equal to:

```
{:post=>{:pic=>"http://s3.amazonaws.com/criticalcity/datas/3524/big_thumb/send-a-letter.jpg", :name=>"Un’istruzione perfetta", :id=>1995, :authors=>"Delilah"}, :user=>{:pic=>"http://s3.amazonaws.com/criticalcity/avatars/537/thumb/DSCN2744.JPG", :name=>"Luci!", :id=>537}}
```

Now I need to output this field as a string (exactly as it is in the database), but when I ask:

```
puts feed_event.data
```

outputs:

```
postpichttp://s3.amazonaws.com/criticalcity/datas/3524/big_thumb/send-a-letter.jpgnameUn’istruzione perfettaid1995authorsDelilahuserpichttp://s3.amazonaws.com/criticalcity/avatars/537/thumb/DSCN2744.JPGnameLuci!
```

Why?
How can I output it as a yaml string?

**UPDATE**

In order to create it I have this in my FeedEvent model:

```
class FeedEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_feed_events, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :users, :through => :user_feed_events

   serialize :data

 end
```

And in order to create a new FeedEvent element I do:

```
feed = FeedEvent.create(:event_type => "comment #{commentable_type}", :type_id => id, :data => {:user => {:id => user.id, :name => user.name, :pic => user.avatar.url(:thumb)}, :comment => {:id => id, :body => body, :commentable_id => commentable_id, :commentable_type => :commentable_type, :commentable_name => commentable.name}})
```

**UPDATE #2**

following nzifnab's hint I used the .to_yaml method, but what Rails outputs in this case is:

```
data: "--- \n:post: \n  :pic: http://s3.amazonaws.com/criticalcity/datas/3524/big_thumb/send-a-letter.jpg\n  :authors: Delilah\n  :name: \"Un\\xE2\\x80\\x99istruzione perfetta\"\n  :id: 1995\n:user: \n  :pic: http://s3.amazonaws.com/criticalcity/avatars/537/thumb/DSCN2744.JPG\n  :name: Luci!\n  :id: 537\n"
```

Also commenting "serialize :data" in the model outputs the same.

Thanks,
Augusto

Comment: how do you serialize it? hash, array, somthing else?

Comment: I updated the question with some details on this.

Comment: Responding to your latest update.  Is that not the value you want?  Isn't that the exact string that's stored in the database?  If you opened up a MySql console session and did `SELECT data FROM feed_events WHERE data IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1` Wouldn't the string saved look like that?  Let me know if you were looking for something else...

Comment: Since I do everything in JSON, I would consider just calling `.to_json` on your hash. Of course you won't get symbols for keys in JSON but the rest should work. You really just want the hash to consume externally or is something else going on?

Comment: Thank you Travis, your suggestion made the work!  JSON is the way to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `feed_data.data` rails has automatically de-serialized your string.  You could print it out like this:

`feed_data.data.inspect` to get the ruby hash representation as a string, but since it's already de-serialized it for you do you need to do anything else?

you can call everything on it like `feed_data.data[:post][:pic]`

I'm not sure what method you can use to grab the raw serialized string from the record, but usually you don't need to.

Comment: I'm trying to output the whole table as a serie of create statements in order to export the table from mysql to mongodb.  I'll try the inpect method and see if it makes the job.

Comment: In that case, maybe go with `feed_data.data.to_yaml`.  Or temporarily remove the `serialize :data` line from your model while you're generating the CREATE statements, that way calling `feed_data.data` will give you the raw stored value.  Just remember to add the `serialize` bit back in afterwards.

Comment: Thanks nzifnab, almost there but still not working.  I updated the question with some new details.

Answer (score 0):

By default, serialization is made in a Hash.

Simply loop it to display it's content:

```
<% feed_event.data.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= "#{key}: #{value}" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm just unsure about nesting level here but you've got the idea.

Comment: Mhhh.. Not sure if this would work as the nesting level varies from row to row...

Comment: I see, so you should create a recursive helper which checks whether it deals with a string or a hash. Clear?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned in your Update, the right way to do this is to put "serialize :data" in your model.

Then, you can access the data attribute as a Hash, that's the default, and it gets automatically persisted when you save your object.

**Important Note:**

One important thing for this to work is that you define the database field as text or string -- not as a binary field -- otherwise this will not work correctly!